# How to whether the UserLocation is inside a MKPolygonview or particular region in iOS MKMapView?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, mkmapview, cllocationmanager

I need to check whether the current user location is inside a particular region, here I use a `MKPolygonView`.I had  added a route in my `MKMapView` and I want to check whether the user is in that particular route or not . I tried the following code but it shows always that I'm in wrong path even if am in that region.
Any idea where I had gone wrong?
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

```
    BOOL exist = NO;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D mapCoordinate = newLocation.coordinate;//user location or annot coord
    MKMapPoint mapPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(mapCoordinate);
    for(MKPolyline *routeLine in overlays)
    {

        NSLog(@"Overlays array count = %d",overlays.count);
        MKPolygonView *polygonView =(MKPolygonView *)[mapView viewForOverlay:routeLine];
        CGPoint polygonViewPoint = [polygonView pointForMapPoint:mapPoint];
        BOOL mapCoordinateIsInPolygon = CGPathContainsPoint(polygonView.path, NULL, polygonViewPoint, NO);
        NSLog(@"mapcoordinate %c",mapCoordinateIsInPolygon);
        if(mapCoordinateIsInPolygon)
        {
            exist = YES;
        }
        else
        {
            exist = NO;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing MKPolygons with MKPolylines. An MKPolyline has a corresponding MKPolylineView - not a MKPolygonView – i.e. your cast is invalid. You should be able to check this by using isKindOfClass on your polygonView to verify what type it is.

An MKPolyline is not a closed path so as far as I know it can't contain anything. There are a couple of options but I think the easiest one in your case is to just create your own closed CGPath from the points in the MKPolyline and test against that.